# Copying selected row from 1 datagrid to another in vb6.0

Tags: vb6

I am making a project on visual basic 6.0 using database made on ms access.
I have made a button named submit and wanted that when I click on the button the  selected row should be copied from the present datagrid to another.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I would advise you of you start as new project, please use .Net. Vb6 isn't supported by Microsoft anymore.

Comment: @Ric.Net so what? that isn't very constructive.

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: @Ric.Net it is supported: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/gp/lifedevtool#Visual%20Basic

Comment: Supporting in this case means, they patch on high security risks. Vb6 is over 17 years of age. By moving on, you benefit from lots of improvements and find yourself writing maybe 20% of the code that you'll need to write in vb6.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a defined number of columns you can do it one cell at a time.

In the click event of the button:

```
Private Sub cmdInsertNew_Click()
    datagridToCopyTo.Columns(0).Text = datagridToCopyFrom.Columns(0).Text
    datagridToCopyTo.Columns(1).Text = datagridToCopyFrom.Columns(1).Text
    datagridToCopyTo.Columns(2).Text = datagridToCopyFrom.Columns(2).Text
End Sub
```